# What is the purpose of using font: inherit?

Tags: css

I just wanted to know why `font: inherit;` is used in Cascading Style Sheets.

Comment: `font: inherit;` is incorrect syntax according to CSS Fonts Module Level 3.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Like the other answers have said, it’s to inherit a CSS property from the parent element.

What the other answers have failed to say is *why you’d need this*. Because, after all, CSS properties are inherited anyway, right?

Well, no. Most are, by default (but link colour isn’t inherited from the parent element, for instance). But consider this case:

```css
p { color: blue; }

div.important { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="important">
    <p>This is a text</p>
</div>
```

Now the text will be blue, not red. If we want the `<p>` to have its parent’s styling rather than its default styling, we have to override its CSS. We could of course repeat the property value (`red`) but that violates DRY (don’t repeat yourself). Instead, we *inherit* it:

```css
div.important p { color: inherit; }
```

Comment: hmm..thts true but font is inherited by `default`.no need of inheriting it!

Comment: @Anirudha It is inherited *by default*, true. But in my example we have explicitly overridden the default: by specifying `p{color:blue}` we have overridden the default behaviour (which is `p{color:inherit}`) so we need to re-instate the inheriting behaviour in the more specific element selector `div.important p`.

Comment: As for using the shorthand `font: inherit`, it's almost never needed. In most cases it's enough to inherit one or two properties at a time, and not everything, unless it's in a CSS reset.

Comment: @KonradRudolph like the others, you also failed to answer why it is needed.  The OP isn't asking about inheritance in general, but specifically related to font properties.

Comment: @cimmanon I’d claim that you can trivially extrapolate this. My example has used `color` because it’s simple. But just substitute `font` and you see why you need it. That shouldn’t be too non-obvious, should it?

Answer (score 10):

The declaration `font:inherit` is used in many “CSS Reset” stylesheets, which have often been copied into various libraries and frameworks. The original [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) by Eric Meyer has `font:inherit`. No specific motivation is given. The overall rationale is said to be “to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on”. But Meyer links to a [previous post](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/) of his where he explains the idea, saying, among other things: “I want all this because I don’t want to take style effects for granted. This serves two purposes. First, it makes me think just that little bit harder about the semantics of my document. With the reset in place, I don’t pick `strong` because the design calls for boldfacing. Instead, I pick the right element—whether it’s `strong` or `em` or `b` or `h3` or whatever—and then style it as needed.”

Several HTML elements have a default rendering in browsers as regards to font properties: headings, form fields, table header cells, some phrase elements, etc. Using CSS Reset, or specifically `font: inherit` means that on browsers supporting the `inherit` value, all such elements are rendered in copy text font, unless otherwise specified in a style sheet.

So this is about a particular methodology (or, as some people might say, ideology or religion) of authoring and design. It has gained popularity and often applied routinely.

Comment: So now we have code that removes bold and then adds it back everytime you want to have strong or a heading tag be bold.  Even though that is a standard default across browsers.  Not currently a fan of Meyer's implementation.  Even though I like his intentions somewhat.

Comment: Same here. I appreciate the intention, but e.g. `font: inherit` makes creating a site-wide font scheme nearly impossible without _extensive_ font styles explicitly set all over the place. It breaks a lot of the 'good' parts of CSS which, let's be honest, there aren't a lot of those to spare to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

> The `font` CSS property is either a shorthand property for setting `font-style`, `font-variant`, `font-weight`, `font-size`, `line-height`, and `font-family`; or a way to set the element's font to a system font, using specific keywords. -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font)

By using `font: inherit;`, it tells an element to inherit those relevant values from its parent container. See the examples below:

**In the 1st group:** you can see there are some special style set by default from the browser, `h1` is bolder and larger it also inherits the relevant values from `body` automatically. However, for the `input` element, it doesn't inherit any of those values, since it's a replaced element and serves its unique purpose.

**In the 2nd group:** It forces those elements to inherit those values from `body` by using `font: inherit;`.

Now, you see what it does. It's entirely up to you when to use it, for instance you might want to use `<h1>` tag for the site logo in the home page, and you probably want to make it look no difference than it appears on other pages. And of course, it's commonly being used in CSS reset frameworks.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
  font-style: italic;
}

.inherit {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<input type="button" value="Button">

<hr>

<h1 class="inherit">Heading</h1>
<input class="inherit" type="button" value="Button">
```

Answer (score 3):

Not all browsers inherit font properties on all elements.  Netscape 4.x was notoriously bad about about inheritance.  Consider the following style:

```
body { background: black; color: white }
```

In Netscape 4.x, the color was not applied to table elements, so you would end up with the default black text inside the table on a black background.

Font properties have the same kind of deal for some elements, particularly form elements (and table elements for older browsers).  It's not uncommon to see a definition like this:

```
table, form { font: inherit }
```

Comment: The historical motivation for this (now widespread) explicit specification of the default is helpful.  __Netscape 4.x was notoriously bad about about inheritance.__

Answer (score 2):

Using `{font:inherit;}` in CSS makes sense because various user agents (a.k.a. browsers) have user agent stylesheet (read: default stylesheet) with something like

```
body
{
    font: -magic-font-from-user-preferences;
}

textarea, input
{
    font: monospace;
}
```

The `{font:inherit;}` is used to workaround the special case where `font` or `font-family` is not inherited by default due to user agent stylesheet but the author of the content wishes the font family to be inherited.

The actual user agent behavior with the value `inherit` differs due to various bugs, unfortunately. Resulting behavior may be closer to author intent than the default value, though.

Answer (score 1):

The `inherit` is used to get the properties from the parent element. In other words, inherit the properties of parent element.

The default property is `inherit`, it means, say you have `div` and a `p`.

```
<div>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Now you give a style:

```
div {font-famlily: Tahoma;}
p {font-family: inherit;}
```

That `font-family` is `inherit`ed to the `p` from its parent element `div`.

Comment: This doesn’t explain why you’d need this.

Answer (score 0):

`inherit` in CSS simply means it inherits the values from parent element, so for example:

```
<div style="font-family: Arial;">
   <p style="font-family: inherit; /* This will inherit the font-family of the parent p*/">
      This text will be Arial..And inherit is default behavior of the browser
   </p>
</div>
```

Here `<p>` inherits the `font-family: Arial;` from it's parent `div`

> You need to use inherit for example in the case of anchor elements,
>   the color property is commonly set to blue in the user agent style
>   sheet. If you wanted to reinforce the importance of the inherited
>   value, you could use the value inherit in an author or user style
>   sheet, overwriting the user agent style sheet declaration.

[More Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritvalue)

Comment: This doesn’t explain why you would need this.

Comment: font is inherited by default..no need of it..[reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html)

Comment: @Anirudha Do you understand the meaning of a reference?

Comment: @Mr.Alien ur `font-family: inherit` doesnt make **sense** nd is **NOT** required..it's a W3C [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html)

Comment: @BoltClock As usual you don't have anything else but to target me, any special reason for this and can you explain why it's a poor example please?

Comment: As Anirudha has said, this is already the default behavior. You're not illustrating why it'd be useful to specify `inherit`, since leaving it out would have exactly the same effect here.

Comment: @BoltClock He said no need of a reference, so do you support this? don't we give references?

Comment: He didn't say no need of a reference. He means there's no need to say `inherit` since it's already the default, and then he provided a reference.