# Inherit font-family property if font not available

Tags: css

I'm trying to get something like this to work:

```
body { 
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

p { 
    font-family: Helvetica, inherit;
}
```

Basically if "Helvetica" is not available on the client's browser, I want the font-family to be inherited from a parent. But it seems to me that I can't use "inherit" in a font priority list. 
How can I achieve something like this without having to copy paste font-family from body?

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. You can use it just like you did. This is something that became available with CSS2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880536/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-font-inherit) is similar and has some answers worthy of a read.
I think the real problem is that Helvetica isn't a free font. So, it just isn't available for widespread use.

> Option 1) If you own the Helvetica font, make an image using that font
>   (for the few lines that you want that specific look for).
>
> Option 2) (as @bjupreti suggested) is to use a substitute font that is widely
>   available.

Comment: If I use it the way I posted, it ignores the priority list and inherits right away. So it displays Verdana even if Helvetica is available.

Comment: Can you show us the corresponding HMTL code?
Also, is there a reason that you don't want to list Helvetica in the body tag as a parent element?

Comment: The HTML code is quite long and it doesnt contain any style tags. The CSS I posted is dumbed down but I'd like Helvetica for a particular selector only.

Answer (score -3):

Font family will automatically be inherited from the parent property. So, all you have to do is:

```
body { 
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
p { 
  font-family: Helvetica; 
}
```

This will automatically inherit the font family of body if there is no Helvetica in end users computer.

Comment: I hope this helps..to know more about how inheritance works on CSS, you can check out this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) below.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I test it by changing the font-family (of p) to a non-existing one, instead of displaying the parent font, it displays the default browser font.

Comment: Have you make sure that you have parent font installed on the computer you test or you have loaded it correctly in browser. You can load it using @font-face in css.  
Now please try this:
```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body { 
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}
p { 
  font-family: Helvetica; 
}
```
This must work :) Happy coding.